# Cannot deploy functions into google cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

I am having trouble deploying my function into google cloud functions. Here is my code for reference:

```
/* eslint-disable max-len */
/* eslint-disable no-unexpected-multiline */
/* eslint-disable func-call-spacing */
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_TEST_KEY);
// eslint-disable-next-line max-len, no-unexpected-multiline

require("dotenv").config();

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//   functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
//   response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });

// API
// App config
const app = express();

// Middlewares
app.use(cors({origin: true}));
// app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());


// API routes
app.get("/", (request, response) => response.status(200).send
("hello world"));
// eslint-disable-next-line space-before-function-paren
// changed 'query' to body
app.post("/payments/create", async (request, response) => {
  const total = request.query.total;
  console.log("Payment Request Received >>>", total);
  try {
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: total, // subunits of the currency
      currency: "usd",
    });
    // ok - created
    response.status(201).send({
      clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    response.status(500).send({error: error.message});
  }
});
// Listen command
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);

// Example endpoint
// http://127.0.0.1:5001/clone-bfd8a/us-central1/api

// http://127.0.0.1:5001/clone-bfd8a/us-central1/api
```

I have reinstalled node-modules directory and my package-lock.json because I got this error:

> Build failed: npm ERR! code EUSAGE\nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! `npm ci` can
> only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or
> npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with
> `npm install` before continuing

However the error still persists. Could it be that there is something wrong with my dependencies in my package.json file? Here is my package.json file for reference:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.1.1",
    "standard": "^17.0.0",
    "stripe": "^10.17.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.30.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Im pretty sure im running the command correctly. I go to my functions folder, where my function is located, and then I run "firebase deploy --only functions". I'm not sure what my problem is. Any ideas why this is happening? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks and happy coding :)